# Android - Get Contact Photo from phone number

Tags: android, photo, contacts

how can I get contact photo from a contact's address (phone number)?

Comment: refer this url:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get contact photo URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738192/how-to-get-contact-photo-uri)

Comment: Try this , maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38992166/4593930

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap retrieveContactPhoto(Context context, String number) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String contactId = null;
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};

        Cursor cursor =
                contentResolver.query(
                        uri,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.default_image);

        try {
            if(contactId != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(),
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactId)));

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                }

                assert inputStream != null;
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return photo;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this solution is working fin except u have to check if contactId is null or not before opening the input stream

Answer (score 9):

I think this vesion works better in all android versions :

```
public   Bitmap getContactsDetails(String address) {
    Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.contact_default_picture);





    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));

    // querying contact data store
    Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);


    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String image_uri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

        if (image_uri != null) {

            try {
                bp = MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),
                                Uri.parse(image_uri));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return   bp;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Call this method to get all contact information.

```
public void readContacts() {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append("......Contact Details.....");
  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
  Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
    null, null, null);
  String phone = null;
  String emailContact = null;
  String emailType = null;
  String image_uri = "";
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
   while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    String id = cur.getString(cur
      .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur
      .getString(cur
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

    image_uri = cur
      .getString(cur
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
    if (Integer
      .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
     System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);
     sb.append("\n Contact Name:" + name);
     Cursor pCur = cr.query(
       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
       null,
       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
         + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
      phone = pCur
        .getString(pCur
          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
      sb.append("\n Phone number:" + phone);
      System.out.println("phone" + phone);
     }
     pCur.close();

     Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
       null,
       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
         + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
     while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
      emailContact = emailCur
        .getString(emailCur
          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
      emailType = emailCur
        .getString(emailCur
          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
      sb.append("\nEmail:" + emailContact + "Email type:" + emailType);
      System.out.println("Email " + emailContact
        + " Email Type : " + emailType);

     }

     emailCur.close();
    }

    if (image_uri != null) {
     System.out.println(Uri.parse(image_uri));
     try {
      bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
        .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),
          Uri.parse(image_uri));
      sb.append("\n Image in Bitmap:" + bitmap);
      System.out.println(bitmap);

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }


    sb.append("\n........................................");
   }

   textDetail.setText(sb);
  }
 }
```

Comment: tnx I use your code with select argument so I can retrieve photo by number

Answer (score 3):

You can use the column below to get the contacts photo uri, **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI**.

Comment: Ok so I have tried this and it definitely does NOT work. Why 4 up-votes I don't understand this website. I can get info from ContactsContracts.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI.      But it appears impossible to get anything related to a photo from CommonDataKinds

Answer (score 1):

This is the function:

```
    public static  Bitmap getContactsDetails(String address) {
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                         R.drawable.default_contact_photo);
        String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = '" + address + "'"; 
        Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, selection,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String image_uri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

             if (image_uri != null) {
                 try {
                  bp = MediaStore.Images.Media
                    .getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),
                      Uri.parse(image_uri));

                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }  
        }
        return bp;
    }
```