# Android - Get contact full-size image

Tags: android, android-image

I'm trying to get a contact's full-size image given a contact id, I came up with this :

```
private Bitmap getUserPhoto(long contactId) {
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        contactId);
    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
        Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver()
            .openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fd.createInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but the image size is too small (Thumbnail)

how can I get the full-size photo of a contact?

Thanks

Comment: When you are getting image from contact it will be as a thumbnail....

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509178/getting-a-photo-from-a-contact

Comment: yes, that what I wrote up there, I need the full size image not the thumbnail, Yume all the solutions there returns a thumbnail too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [openContactPhotoInputStream(ContentResolver cr, Uri contactUri, boolean preferHighres)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20boolean%29), if you have original image in your phone. And set preferHighres TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You can **resize** Bitmap

```
private Bitmap getUserPhoto(long contactId) {
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        contactId);
    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
        Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver()
            .openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fd.createInputStream()), newWidth, newHeight, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

newWidth and newHeight are the Int values.

Comment: otherwise u can use CONTENT_MAX_DIMENSIONS_URI instead of CONTENT_URI like this :'ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_MAX_DIMENSIONS_URI,
        contactId);'

Comment: no suck field CONTENT_MAX_DIMENSIONS_URI in Contacts, it does exist in DisplayPhoto, anyways this can't help me since it requires min api 14, thanks anyway