# Is it safe to use the content:// URI to get the user contact photo in Android?

Tags: android

Is it safe to use this URI `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/<contact_id>/photo` to get the contact photo?
Because I was using a query  through the `ContentResolver` but since every time it brought me the same URI format (or null, sometimes), I thought I could save some processing and construct the string directly, only changing the contact_id, which I already have.

But I would like to know if it is safe to use it, like in this example Chosen Answer: [Getting a Photo from a Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509178/getting-a-photo-from-a-contact)

Is it different in some Android devices or Android versions?

Comment: No intention to at least acknowledge my answer so I'm going to remove it. More wasted time...