# I have to Display Contacts info (Name, Number, Image) of all contacts in a List View, using custom adapter which extends base adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

**I have created a `ListView` which should Display Contact-(Name,Number,Image).**

**I retrieved the name and number but, failed to display image.**

*I used custom adapter here is the adapter code*

```
public class PranzAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
Context c;

PranzAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleRow> listItem){
    c = context;
    list= listItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,null,false);

    TextView name   = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    SingleRow singleRow = list.get(position);

    name.setText(singleRow.name);
    number.setText(singleRow.number);

 //Error is this, Previously when any contact doesn't have image it pass `null`  

  if (singleRow.image!= null) {
        image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(singleRow.image));
    }
    return row;
 }
}
```

**Update: I didn't put any default Image for the contact Image, so if any contact doesn't have Image it is throwing `NullPointer` so you can put a default Image or you have to handle the Exception using `if` condition.**

*I can display the name and number but while retrieving the image there is problem.*

**Here is the code for getting the  contact info**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;

ArrayList<SingleRow> listItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listItem = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    String id;
    String name;
    String number;
    String image;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            id   = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                     number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                     image = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

                    SingleRow s = new SingleRow(name,number,image);
                    listItem.add(s);
                }
                pCur.close();

            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    list.setAdapter(new PranzAdapter(this, listItem));
 }
}
```

*Here is the model class I Used for Individual contact:*

```
public class SingleRow {

String name;
String number;
String image;

//Constructor for Single row
SingleRow (String name,String number,String  image){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your requirement but you have to first try out yourself!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3509210/3117296) is a SO post that demonstrates the same thing.

Comment: Would you please post some code that you have tried?

Comment: @PareshMayani please open the question! I gave all the details which i can provide. if any more required please ask me!

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov, I posted the code please go through it!

Comment: @praneethkumar voted for open!

Comment: Thanks to every one who voted to open the question!

Comment: @Amsheer I posted the code please go through it!

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov, I posted my code please go through once! I got every  thing but, the prob is if any contact don't have a Image then the application got crash! how to handle it  any idea!

Comment: @praneethkumar, what is the error? Post your logcat output.

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov: the app crashes when I add a new contact with out a contact image.

Comment: @PareshMayani, why it is still down voted!? and bcoz of this I cant ask any new Questions! please resolve this.
it's saying:
- "Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more."

Comment: @praneethkumar As you have asked a complete question, I have up voted this time but next time please make sure you would ask a question with all the required information!

Comment: @PareshMayani: Definitely, I'm leaning  and following the rules! and thank you so much! for every thing!

Comment: Cheers...keep up learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is here:

```
image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(temp.image));
```

If your contact has no image, you are trying to parse a `null`.

I am not 100% sure but as you havn't provided any stack trace I guess this is the problem.

Comment: Thank you! yeah i used a loop to sort it! but is that corect way?
        if (temp.image!= null) {
            iV.setImageURI(Uri.parse(temp.image));
        }
        else {
        }

Comment: If I were you, I would do it the same way :)

Comment: Please up vote my  Question if u feel it is correct to ask here! so that I can ask some other question here!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html

sample project is also ther for you to check. pls go through this

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what i do:

- Custom Adapter:

  ```
  package com.example.admin.lugaresfavoritos;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.database.DataSetObserver;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.provider.MediaStore;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.ListAdapter;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Arrays;


  public class Adaptador_lista_lugares extends BaseAdapter {

  private ArrayList<Lugar> arrayLugares;
  private LayoutInflater inflador;
  private Context contexto;




  public Adaptador_lista_lugares(ArrayList<Lugar> arrayLugares, Context context) {
      this.arrayLugares = arrayLugares;
      this.inflador = (LayoutInflater) context
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      this.contexto = context;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return arrayLugares.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Lugar getItem(int position) {
      return arrayLugares.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return arrayLugares.get(position).getId();
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      Lugar lugar = arrayLugares.get(position);

      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflador.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista_lugares, null);
      }

      TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_elemento_lista);
      ImageView foto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto_elemento_lista);

      nombre.setText(lugar.getNombre());
      foto.setImageResource(lugar.getPhoto());

      return convertView;

  }


  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
      return arrayLugares.isEmpty();
  }



  }
  ```
- XML for each element of Custom Adapter:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:id="@+id/elemento_lista">


      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/foto_elemento_lista"
          android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
          android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
          android:contentDescription="foto"
          android:longClickable="false"
          android:paddingTop="5dp"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:text="@string/lugarPorDefecto"
          android:id="@+id/nombre_elemento_lista"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/foto_elemento_lista" />


  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Well, this Custom Adapter is made for Places ( Lugar in Spanish ), Each place has  some attributes, including a photo and a name, so. As you can see, when I create the adapter, i send him the array of places. The method `getView()` returns the layout inflated for each element of the array. You will have to create custom contact class or something similar, with name of the contact and photo, create the array of contacts, and send that array when create the custom adapter.

-In activity containing listView:

```
    lugares = cargarListaLugares2(); // Method to create arrayList of the elemnt you want
    mAdapter = new Adaptador_lista_lugares(lugares, getActivity()); //Create the custom adapter with that array
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter); //Set the custom adapter
```

Hope it helps you,

Regards

Edit: simplified my code logic so you can understand better.

Edit 2: Acitivty example using this:

-XML for the activity ( containing the listView )

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.admin.lugaresfavoritos.MainActivity">

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    </FrameLayout>
```

- Activity Code

  ```
  package com.example.admin.lugaresfavoritos;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;


  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Iterator;


  public class MainActivity extends Activity {


      private ArrayList<Lugar> lugares;
      private ListView mListView;
      private ListAdapter mAdapter;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);  // Set the xml layout containing listView

          //load array of places( in your case contacts )
          lugares = cargarListaLugares();
          // create the adapter
          mAdapter = new Adaptador_lista_lugares(lugares, this); //parameters are array and context

          mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); //instanciate the listView
          mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter); //set the adapter to the listView


      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_mapa, menu);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
          // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
          // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
          int id = item.getItemId();

          if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
              return true;
          }

          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }


      //method to create array from localDB(In this case places )
      public ArrayList<Lugar> cargarListaLugares(){



          ArrayList<Lugar> lugares2 = new ArrayList<>();

          Integer id;
          String nombre;
          String direccion;
          double longitud;
          double latitud;
          Integer telefono;
          String url;
          String comentario;
          double valoracion;
          String foto;
          boolean favorito;

          lugares2.clear();

          BDLugares GestorBD= new BDLugares(this,"lugares", null,1);
          SQLiteDatabase db = GestorBD.getWritableDatabase();
          Cursor c;

          c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lugares", null);



          while (c.moveToNext()) {

              id = c.getInt(0);
              nombre = c.getString(1);
              direccion = c.getString(2);
              longitud = c.getDouble(3);
              latitud = c.getDouble(4);
              telefono = c.getInt(5);
              url = c.getString(6);
              comentario = c.getString(7);
              valoracion = c.getDouble(8);
              foto = c.getString(9);
              favorito  =(c.getInt(10)>0);

              Lugar lug = new Lugar(id,nombre,direccion,longitud, latitud, telefono, url, comentario, valoracion, foto, favorito);

              lugares2.add(lug);

          }
          c.close();
          db.close();

          return lugares2;
      }


  }
  ```

Comment: i use this in a fragment wich have a bit diferent code, so ill try to make a quick activity example

Comment: Also changed in adapter, i was setting default photo for place, instead using the place.getPhoto() wich returns the path

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and create a Custom Adapter..

```
   public class CustomAdapteCountry extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
   public Resources res;
   private LayoutInflater inflater;
   private String val,imagename="photos";
private SpinnerModel tempSpin;

public CustomAdapteCountry(MainActivity context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList objects,Resources resLocal) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId,objects);

     activity = context;
        data     = objects;
        res      = resLocal;     
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);
    tempSpin=null;
    tempSpin=(SpinnerModel) data.get(position);

     TextView label        = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
        ImageView companyLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);   

        label.setText(tempSpin.getCompanyName());  

        if(val==null)
        {         

             String value= (tempSpin.getImage()).replaceAll("\\s+","");


              int va=(res.getIdentifier("com.all.world.news.finder:drawable/"+value,null,null));

              if(va==0) {
                 companyLogo.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.all.world.news.finder:drawable/"+value,null,null));
              }
              else{
                 companyLogo.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("com.all.world.news.finder:drawable/"+value,null,null));                 
              }
        }


         return row;
       } 

}
```

Call this adapter for this way..

```
 private CustomAdapteCountry adapter;



  Resources res = getResources(); 
 adapter=new CustomAdapteCountry(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,country ,res);
    countryname.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Try this Custom adapter and show the image with name..

Comment: i want my custom adapter to extend a base adapter! and i want to display contact image.

Comment: yeah it will return the image but! if only every contact have a image. If I keep any of the contact image (null) I mean with out image it's throwing error. how to handle it? any suggestions?

Comment: which content have not image the add a default image.. and add it

Comment: Can you elaborate! I didn't get you