# Android get RAW_CONTACT image uri

Tags: android, android-contacts

To get contact photo uri you can simply fallow the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html):

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
return Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

But in my case I want to show all the RAW_CONTACTS that are part of a single contact, there for I need their high res photo uri. So how can I obtain one?

Note that I am not interested in the thumbnail BLOB that you can find in the Data table under the `Contacts.Photo.PHOTO` column, but the high res image.

Comment: have you tried [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3509210/3800164), seems like useful for your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto`,

Here's the official usage example from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.html) (it's for **writing** a photo into a RawContact):

```
public void writeDisplayPhoto(long rawContactId, byte[] photo) {
     Uri rawContactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
             ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId),
             RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd =
             getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(rawContactPhotoUri, "rw");
         OutputStream os = fd.createOutputStream();
         os.write(photo);
         os.close();
         fd.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // Handle error cases.
     }
 }
```

Here's how to read it:

```
public byte[] readDisplayPhoto(long rawContactId) {
     byte[] photo;
     Uri rawContactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
             ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId),
             RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(rawContactPhotoUri, "r");
         FileInputStream is = fd.createInputStream();
         is.read(photo);
         is.close();
         fd.close();
         return photo
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // Handle error cases.
     }
 }
```